# Objective-C app crash “message sent to deallocated instance 0x..”

Tags: objective-c, textfield, resignfirstresponder, crash

i have a table view with cells containing textFields in it.

there are more than 20 rows in table.

when i'm entering something into text fields and scrolling after sometime my app is crashed  i'm getting this error.

```
message sent to deallocated instance 
#0  0x00f5e09b in objc_msgSend ()
#1  0x040cfb5a in dyld_stub_strlcat ()
#2  0x001190d6 in -[UIResponder resignFirstResponder] ()
#3  0x000e097f in -[UITextField resignFirstResponder] ()
#4  0x00119293 in -[UIResponder becomeFirstResponder] ()
#5  0x002e1961 in -[UITextInteractionAssistant setFirstResponderIfNecessary] ()
#6  0x002e45e2 in -[UITextInteractionAssistant oneFingerTap:] ()
#7  0x002db4f2 in -[UIGestureRecognizer _updateGestureWithEvent:] ()
#8  0x002d74fe in -[UIGestureRecognizer _delayedUpdateGesture] ()
#9  0x002ddafc in _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateObserver ()
#10 0x002ddce1 in _UIGestureRecognizerUpdateGesturesFromSendEvent ()
#11 0x0007132a in -[UIWindow _sendGesturesForEvent:] ()
#12 0x0006cca3 in -[UIWindow sendEvent:] ()
#13 0x0004fc37 in -[UIApplication sendEvent:] ()
#14 0x00054f2e in _UIApplicationHandleEvent ()
#15 0x01031992 in PurpleEventCallback ()
#16 0x00dd9944 in __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ ()
#17 0x00d39cf7 in __CFRunLoopDoSource1 ()
#18 0x00d36f83 in __CFRunLoopRun ()
#19 0x00d36840 in CFRunLoopRunSpecific ()
#20 0x00d36761 in CFRunLoopRunInMode ()
#21 0x010301c4 in GSEventRunModal ()
#22 0x01030289 in GSEventRun ()
#23 0x00058c93 in UIApplicationMain ()
#24 0x00001cd9 in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff058) at main.m:14
(gdb)
```

I would appreciate any help anyone can offer.

Answer (score 3):

This error occurs when you are trying to access released object.

From your posted stack it seems that you are trying to call method `resignFirstResponder` of `UITextField`.

Check all your `UITextField` instances or put some more source code.